# product of functions are in L^2 space

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question. If we are given $k$ linear subspaces $\{V_j:1\leq j\leq k\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, each $V_j$ has dimension $d$. Assume we know $kd\leq n$, and the space spanned by $\{V_j:1\leq j\leq k\}$ is of dimension $kd$. Denoting $\pi_j$ as the orthogonal projection: $\mathbb{R}^m\to V_j$. For functions $f_j\in L^2(V_j)$, can we conclude the product of $f_j\circ\pi_j$ for $1\leq j\leq k$, is in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Thanks for the comment and answer below!

If we add a cut off function on the product, namely, now we consider $\Pi_{j=1}^k (f_j\circ\pi_j)\eta(x)$, where $\eta(x)$ is a smooth function with compact support. The other conditions keep the same. Is it in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Thanks!

Comment: Try considering simple cases.  Consider $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $V$ the $1$-dimensional subspace spanned by $(1,0)^T$.  If $f\in L^2(V)$, what can you say about $f\circ\pi_V$?

Comment: I see. Thanks! This one is not in $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no:

Consider the following example. $n=2$, $V_1 = \mathbb{R}$ the first coordinate or $x$-axis, and $V_2$ the second coordinate or $y$-axis. 
Then $f_1(x)=\chi_{[0,1]}(x)$ is clearly in $L^2(V_1)$. But $(f_1 \circ \pi_1) (x,y) = \chi_{[0,1]\times \mathbb{R}}(x,y)$ is clearly not in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see why it is not in $L^2$. What if we add a cut off fucntion on it? Is it in $L^2$? I just edited the question. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, if you cut off function, has support in some intervall $[a,b]^n$, then the resulting $L^2$ norm will be bounded by the $V_1$ $L^2$ norm times $(b-a)^n$.

Comment: Thank you! Is the condition that the span is of dimension $kd$ imply that we can make coordinates of these $V_j$?

Comment: I just realized, that I misunderstood your question, and the example I gave was no counterexample, as you required the function in $y$ to be square integrable as well.